# Get value from JSON object in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, json

I'm having troubles access a JSON result in Javascript. To be more specific how to access the value in the response.

This is my code:
**Custom class**

```
public class ClientModel
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public String Text1 { get; set; }
    public String Text2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

**Generic handler**:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(new ClientModel()
 {
   Text1 = "aaa",
   Guid = Guid.Parse("e2e2c9f2-5ddd-4a7e-a223-ddec42e08afb"),
   Text2 = "bbb",
   Date = DateTime.Now
 }));
```

The response in the browser is

```
{"Guid":"e2e2c9f2-5ddd-4a7e-a223-ddec42e08afb","Text1":"aaa","Text2":"bbb","Datum":"\/Date(1332790780933)\/"}
```

Looks like a JSON object, right?

Let's assume this result is in a variable called `result`.

**How can I access the values inside this object?**

`result[0]` returns `{`
`result.Text1` is `undefined`
`result["Text1"]` is `undefined`

Comment: I am always surprised when someone feels the need to do this in this manner and not let the platform do it through a web service  decorated properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found the solution myself. I hope it helps somebody else in the future.

I'm using a `.ajax` call and I've set `dataType: "html"` instead of `dataType: "json"`

Now `result.Text1` works